# Compress and decompress chunk of bytes in inputstream

Tags: java, inputstream, compression

I am printing a chunk from inputstream by using

```
int skip = in.skip(1024); //skip first 1024b

int end = in.available(); // remaining size in b

for (int i = skip; i < end; i++) {

    //prints chunk of data from in-stream from skip till end

     System.out.println(in.read()); 

}
```

instead of printing from skip to end, i want to compress the bytes between skip to end (in.read()) 
can someone help me to first compress and then decompress the same

---

i tried this

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(ChunkZipName);
GZIPOutputStream chunkZipper = new GZIPOutputStream (fos); 
for (int i = skip; i < end; i++) {
chunkZipper.write(in.read()); }
```

but it write only 10bytes.. remaining bytes r skipped ... is this correct usage of GZIPOutputStream ???

Comment: Use GZipInputStream and GZipOutputStream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wrap a `GZIPOutputStream` / `GZIPInputStream` around your real stream.

```
out = new GZIPOutputStream (out);
```

**BTW:**
If you want to really skip exactly 1024 bytes you **have to check** the return value of `skip` and repeat with the remaining bytes because in some cases (buffers) the method does not skip fully to the desired position.